# How to get current user's properties into dict format

Tags: python, django, dictionary

How to get current user's properties into dict format like given below... I tried `request.user.__dict__`  and `request.user.__class__.__dict__` but not giving that data

```
{
    '_state': < django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7fa2c8a14da0 > ,
    'id': 1,
    'password': 'gVFDqqWHxJhnrkyYANJb',
    'last_login': None,
    'is_superuser': False,
    'username': 'ualexander',
    'first_name': 'Valerie',
    'last_name': 'Jones',
    'email': 'gonen@yahoo.com',
    'is_staff': False,
    'is_active': True,
    'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 6, 10, 52, 24, 142211, tzinfo = < UTC > )
}
```

## views.py

```
  def dashboard_view(request):
    print(request.user.__dict__)
```

## my output

```
{'_setupfunc': <function AuthenticationMiddleware.process_request.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7fe71c6bfea0>, '_wrapped': <User: nitin>}
```

Comment: Please include your code and output.

Comment: I have pasted it @glhr

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do this.

```
request.user.__class__.objects.filter(pk=request.user.id).values().first()
```

It will return sample output like this

```
{'id': 1, 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 5, 10, 44, 19, 110212, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'is_superuser': True, 'username': 'example', 'first_name': 'first', 'last_name': 'last', 'is_staff': True, 'is_active': True, 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 5, 9, 31, 16, 736841, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 5, 9, 31, 16, 962971, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'modified_at': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 5, 9, 31, 16, 962992, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'deleted_at': None, 'is_deleted': False, 'user_id': 1, 'password': 'pbkdf2_sha256$150000$JDcvyHbn1aFI$8gzgVZP/+bvZVQ/OISSF/+BJcJuAJE7zGU4rpBVpA8M=', 'email': 'examle@gmail.com', 'member_from': datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'phone_number': '011111111'}
```

**Update:**
You want to get objects as dictionary for request user.
In django `request.user` not give you data as dict format
To get your desired result, You need to do some tricky task.

```
request.user.__class__.objects.filter(pk=request.user.id).values().first()
```

here `request.user.__class__` is result the model name, then filter this with current user.

Comment: I don't use Django but something looks very cumbersome with `.__class__.objects.values()`. Is this actually the correct approach here?

Comment: I update my answer with some explanation @ Nikhil and @roganjosh